# Django Test error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: django, testing, django-manage.py

I am trying to run tests in django which are placed in tests folder.Following is the output.

```
python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management __init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command klass = load_command_class(app_name,subcommand)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",line 40, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands __init__.py", line 10, in <module> import  django.template.loaders.app_directories
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders /app_directories.py", line 23, in <module> mod = import_module(app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module> from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module> class Permission(models.Model):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__ return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 196, in __getitem__self.ensure_defaults(alias)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 174, in ensure_defaults conn.setdefault('ATOMIC_REQUESTS', False)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Can some one help me with this ?
I have tried solving by checking the enviornment and i think its correct.Tests run good in production with same enviornment.

Database Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
    'NAME': 'projectx',        
    'USER': 'xyz',
    'PASSWORD': 'xyz',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '',         
}
}
if 'test' in sys.argv:
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test_project',
    'USER': 'xyz',
    'PASSWORD': 'xyz',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '',         
},
```

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @rnevius Yes thats the full error i am getting

Comment: Please show your database settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  updated the database settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a stray comma after the end of your test DATABASES dict, which turns it into a single-item tuple. Remove that final comma.